# Why did McCarthy reintroduce the segment as a unit of analysis in CV phonology?

Tags: phonology

What were the explanatory shortcomings in Autosegmental Phonology which motivated McCarthy to re-introduce  the segment as a unit of representation in CV Phonology?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more accurate characterization of the history is that McCarthy did not adopt Goldsmith's radical desegmentalization, so from M's POV this was maintenance of the status quo. M does not address the question, so one can only speculate. There are a few prominent reasons that I believe most explain this. First, G's idea was rather speculative and rationalist, and the details implementation of radical desegmentalization remained to be worked out, so that it wasn't practical to actually adopt the proposal right out of the box. Second, recall that M is a strong proponent of the OCP *qua* universal constraint, which prohibits adjacent identical segments – but not features (G on the other hand rejects the OCP). The OCP facts (especially the **ssm* fact of Arabic) necessitate a robust notion of "segment".

Third, M had available to him the now expired additional theoretical construct "projection" which gives the appearance of featural autonomy without denying the segment. Forth, M's concern is fundamentally about syllable structure, which is maximally remote from the kind of feature concerns that inspired G. Segment lengthening and shortening, which are at the center of his concerns, are most problematic for a radical desegmentalized theory, lacking a unified thing that you can have two of. Related to this is the fact that most of the time, a segment can have only one specification of a feature (tone are major exceptions), and without a hardcore segment, this fact is hard to encode in the theory. Finally, M introduces a competing theory that each morpheme defines a separate tier, which if crossed with featural decomposition, would make the head explode (though he does not explicitly reject feature decomposition, still his focus directed is away from feature autonomy).